# Why can I not start Visual Studio 2012 or Catalyst Control Center?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Up until today, I could open and work with Visual Studio 2012 on my computer. Now when I open it, it shows the splash screen, then the main application window without any projects loaded - but doesn't get any further than that. The mouse icon is still that of a spinning circle (i.e. it is busy doing something).

If I click in the window a couple of times this message shows:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy
>   Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an internal operation to complete. If you regularly encounter this delay during normal usage, please report this problem to Microsoft.

I can't even uninstall Visual Studio 2012 since the uninstaller hangs when it opens.

The same thing happens if I open Catalyst Control Center. The window opens but I cannot interact with any menus or the window decorations themselves.

What is going on?

Comment: Not to seem sarcastic, but have you tried to restart your computer?

Comment: Or look a the Event logs, or do a disk check, or run Process Monitor, System Restore, etc.?  We'll need way more information to answer you.

Comment: I have restarted my computer. I did do a disk check on boot, but it didn't fix my problems. I don't know where to begin with the event logs, system restore is turned off on this system. I tried Procmon and captured a lot of events but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: You may have to find/pay someone who does then, as we can't see it from here. :)

Comment: Open the Windows event log (under control panel\administrative tools) and search for entries mentioning the two problematic apps. Add those to your question along with any regularly repeating errors from the logs. Then we may be able to help.